# Does it break immutability of object?

Tags: php, class, immutability

I was reading this: https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2017/03/php-and-immutability/

and came upon an example, so its the perfect immutable class:

```
class Immutable {
    private $skater, $trick;

    public function __construct($skater, $trick) {
        $this->skater = $skater;
        $this->trick = $trick;
    }

    public function getSkater() {
        return $this->skater;
    }

    public function getTrick() {
        return $this->trick;
    }
}
```

so far so good. But not breakable, as the article mentioned:

```
$x = new Immutable('Hawk', 'Frontside 540');
$x->__construct('Song', 'Darkslide');
```

it was rewritten like this:

```
class Immutable {
    private $skater, $trick;
    private $mutable = true;

    public function __construct($skater, $trick) {
        if (false === $this->mutable) {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Constructor called twice.');
        }
        $this->skater = $skater;
        $this->trick = $trick;
        $this->mutable = false;
    }

    public function getSkater() {
        return $this->skater;
    }

    public function getTrick() {
        return $this->trick;
    }
}
```

but now changing `mute` value itself breaks immutability, right? :)

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html

Answer (score 2):

No, it would not since the value is only set in the constructor and never changed afterwards. So it fits the definition of immutability. I would rename `$mutable` to `$isCreated` or something, because you can't really change the mutable property of the class with this property, it's named misleadingly in my opinion.

On some level, however, object immutability in PHP is not possible at all, because:

> Immutability does not imply that the object as stored in the computer's memory is  unwriteable. Rather, immutability is a compile-time construct that indicates what a programmer can do through the normal interface of the object, not necessarily what they can absolutely do

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Violating_immutability))

Since there is no "compile-time" in PHP and the `$mutable` property is evaluated at run-time, it would seem to violate this concept from the get-go.

On another level, using the same quote, "the normal interface" would be what your first example represents. Calling the constructor method directly and not via `new` is totally outside of any normal usage. So, you could say that the class without setters for its properties is already immutable by the convention of "through the normal interface".

Basically, you're asking an academic question but trying to solve a real-world issue of making absolutely certain, an object's properties cannot under any circumstances be changed after instantiation. But then the concept of "immutability" doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

There is fundamental no difference between:

```
  private $mutable = true;
```

And later (at construction) changing that to `false` then:

```
 private $skater
```

And then changing that to something else later (at construction).  When you don't set an initial value what you are saying is this:

```
private $skater = null;
```

You can easily check this by doing `var_dump($this->skater)` before setting a value, and it will say `null`.  So in reality, in the first example, you are already changing a null value to something else.  [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d67d45ba9895370e42dbb5c20c0f0a097399c7e)  So really what is the difference between changing `null` and changing `false` at construction?

Rather or not you consider that Immutable is a matter of opinion.  The only thing in PHP that is Immutable is constants.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your immutable class accepts only primitive data types (such as string, int, float, bool), your class should be fairly immutable. But once you pass objects or streams, it's not immutable. Even with Value Objects, it is not easy to get a true immutable object.

Comment: That's the weirdest thing I've heard this year. `class Latitude(float $lat); class Longitude (float $lon); class Point(Latitude $lat, Longitude $lon); class Time(int $unixTime); class Location(Point $position, Time $time);`. As long as the methods of the object does not mutate the state of the object, it is immutable. I wonder what do you mean by "it is not easy to get a true immutable object".

Comment: @emix Do you know how references works and what an "unwanted side effect" is?